# Overlay ggplot grouped tiles with polygon border depending on extra factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon, tile

I have a data frame with x and y positions and two factor columns blocknr and cat:

```
dput(testData)
structure(list(xpos = c(2L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 
3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
8L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
5L, 7L, 2L), ypos = c(1L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 
10L, 1L, 4L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 3L, 4L, 
7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 7L), blocknr = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), cat = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("xpos", "ypos", "blocknr", 
"cat"), row.names = c(NA, -77L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've made the following ggplot code to make 2D overview:

```
ggplot(data=testData, aes(x=xpos,y=ypos))+
geom_tile(aes(fill=cat), colour = "white")+
scale_fill_manual(values = c('A' = '#F8766D','C' = '#8ABF54','B' = '#C1DDA5'))+
geom_text(aes(x=xpos,y=ypos,label=blocknr),size=3)+
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.5, ymax + 0.5)) +
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0.5, xmax + 0.5)) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,xmax,1))+
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(1,ymax,1))+
#geom_polygon(aes(group=blocknr))+
theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "white"),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank())
```

which produces the following result:
[image]

Now I would like to highlight each group of blocknrs by drawing a border around them as shown below:
[image]

I've played around with `geom_polygon`, `geom_path`, but I can't quite find a way to do this. Is there a general way to achieve this in `ggplot` without constructing an algorithm to compute where each line should be and add those lines as a `geom_segment`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this with standard ggplot2 tile options. But it's not to much trouble to constuct them if you do it as segments. For example

```r
ymax <- max(testData$ypos)
xmax <- max(testData$xpos)

m <- matrix(0, nrow=ymax, ncol=xmax)
m[as.matrix(testData[,2:1])] <- testData[,3]
```

Here we are basically taking all the row/col assignment data and creating a matrix that essentially looks like the plot but we will with the block numbers. Now, we will scan for the locations we need to add "wall" by looking for changes in the block numbers as we go across each row and column separately.

```r
has.breaks<-function(x) ncol(x)==2 & nrow(x)>0

hw<-do.call(rbind.data.frame, Filter(has.breaks, Map(function(i,x) 
    cbind(y=i,x=which(diff(c(0,x,0))!=0)), 1:nrow(m), split(m, 1:nrow(m)))))
vw<-do.call(rbind.data.frame, Filter(has.breaks, Map(function(i,x)
    cbind(x=i,y=which(diff(c(0,x,0))!=0)), 1:ncol(m), as.data.frame(m))))
```

And you can add calls to `geom_segments` to add the horizontal and vertical walls to the plot.

```r
ggplot(data=testData, aes(x=xpos,y=ypos))+
    geom_tile(aes(fill=cat), colour = "white")+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c('A' = '#F8766D','C' = '#8ABF54','B' = '#C1DDA5'))+
    geom_text(aes(x=xpos,y=ypos,label=blocknr),size=3)+
    geom_segment(data=hw, aes(x=x-.5, xend=x-.5, y=y-.5, yend=y+.5))+
    geom_segment(data=vw, aes(x=x-.5, xend=x+.5, y=y-.5, yend=y-.5))+
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.4, ymax + 0.6)) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0.4, xmax + 0.6)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,xmax,1))+
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(1,ymax,1))+
    theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `desplot` package will do this for you (using `lattice`):

```
library(desplot)
desplot(cat ~ xpos*ypos, testData, out1=blocknr, text=blocknr, main="testData")
```

[image]